# flex 4 - 3d Layout and column chart (Matrix)

Tags: charts, flex4, 3d

We have a requirement in flex, where we need to have a 3D layout base and inside it we have 2 column charts with 3D effect.

I have attached the screen shot for reference. [image]

I have seen couple of samples in which there are 3d effects but not like the one which i have attached.

Wanted to know, whether it is possible to achieve using Flex 4. Otherwise we need to use flash inorder to achieve this. I have seen the exact sample in flash,

http://www.irishlife.ie/iframe/pension-calculator-2.0.html

Need to build this using FLEX 4. So in case of any samples or thought process of how to achieve this please let me know.

Thanks in Advance,

Regards

Srinivasan.C

Answer (score 0):

amCharts will do this with Flex 4.

See for example: http://flex.amcharts.com/examples/stacked_3d_column_chart

Answer (score 0):

You can use AnyChart
http://anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/
you can download both .swf or .swc files from the said site.